# Hyperplane Areangements and contraction.

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids, algebraic-combinatorics

I am trying to understand an idea presented in McNulty book, matriods a geometric introduction about the new hyperplane arrangement $\mathcal{A}^{''} = \{ H \cap H_x | H \in \mathcal{A}\}$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is an affine arrangement of hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^d$ and $H_x \in \mathcal{A}$ and $x$ is a point $\in M(\mathcal{A})$ and so corresponds to a hyperplane $H_x$ in the arrangement.

The book is saying that $$M(\mathcal{A}^{''}) = M (\mathcal{A})/x$$
i.e., the matroid of the induced hyperplane arrangement in x equal the contraction of the matroid of the hyperplane arrangement.

I am not very sure why this statement is correct, can someone show me any kind of proof of it? I am learning matroids by myself so I am not very good at it.

Comment: Could you explain what the matroid associated with an arrangement is? For instance, what are the bases, or independent sets, or circuits ( a full description).

Comment: If I remember correctly the book does not specify a specific matroid, this was chapter 7 of the book.@MathieuRundström

Comment: Please [edit] your post to correct the citation of the book.  Please provide the title of the book, with proper capitalization, and provide the full name of the author.  Where does the book say that?  Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.